# How to git merge entire files?

Tags: git

I am trying to merge my development branch with the master branch, on which someone ran a code formatting tool that has altered almost every line of code.  Now even with "strategy=recursive -X theirs" the merged output is garbage; it often includes two copies of many lines, one with the tool's edits and one with mine.  (I suppose the two are so different that they are treated as independent non-conflicting new code.)

I want to run a merge which takes the *entire file* from my branch if I made *any* changes to that file, but doesn't throw away changes to files I didn't touch.  Is this possible without manually copying over the files one by one?

Comment: I don’t suppose you could just revert the master branch?

Comment: You could automate the "manual" approach: write a script that parses ```git diff-tree `git merge-base my-branch their-branch` my-branch``` and loops with a `git checkout my-branch -- <file>` on each modified file. Do that in a sandbox sitting on their-branch, then use a `git merge -s theirs` (or `git merge -s ours`) to finish the job.

Comment: And first, strangle the person who thought it was OK to run a code formatting tool on the whole code base. Please.

Comment: I agree with @matt you should revert the formatting in affected files in separated commit or PR to the master branch. Otherwise your development would be a mess to readers.